# cakephp 3 table naming convention

Tags: database-design, cakephp-3.0

I'm kinda new to cakephp and I'm having some doubts when trying to create tables which conform to the cakephp table naming and structure standard. Here is an example, I need to create tables to store sales records.

table

```
sales
```

column

```
id (PK)
title
description
quantity
price
user_id
created
modified
```

table

```
sale_details
```

column

```
id (PK)
sale_id (FK)
product_id
quantity
price
created
modified
```

Does it work this way?

Comment: that works that way !

Answer (score 0):

That works well and you can try out CakePHP [Inflector](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/inflector.html) for that.

> You need tables in pluralization form and Inflector class takes a
>   string and can manipulate it to handle word variations such as
>   pluralizations or camelizing and is normally accessed statically.

You can go here https://inflector.cakephp.org to get pularize form of any string.

```
eg: 1.people => people
    2.big_apple => big_apples
    3.sale_detail => sale_details
```